# numpy tostring equivalent to numpy fromstring

Tags: python, numpy

Numpy has a neat function [`numpy.fromstring`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html).

It also seems to have a neat function [`numpy.chararray.tostring`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.tostring.html).

How do I convert `\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00` to a normal ASCII string, which I can write to a file?

Comment: whats wrong with writing that to file? what do you want to write instead? `with open('x','w') as f: f.write('\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00')` works fine for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I was looking for here [`numpy.ndarray.tofile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html)

Answer (score 2):

numpy arrays have a `tostring()` method

```
In [1]: np.ones(3).tostring()
Out[1]: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?'
```

note that the name is wrong, it returns bytes not strings (which happens to be the same in python 2 but not python 3).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
np.fromstring('\x01\x02', dtype=np.uint8)
```